# Accessing AD without a user name / password for read only access

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have no problems accessing AD with code like:

> DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry (ldap, ldapUser,
>   ldapPassword);

Is there a way to access AD via DirectoryEntry without having to provide a user name / password. In this particular case, I just need to read some attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Server 2003 and later do not allow anonymous queries against AD (for the most part).  Make sure your AD Server is properly configured to allow anonymous access.

How-to fix (for Win 2k8):
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816788(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

yes you can

```
  String strPath="LDAP://DC=onecity,DC=corp,DC=fabrikam,DC=com";

  // Create a new DirectoryEntry with the given path.
  DirectoryEntry  objDE=new DirectoryEntry(strPath);

  foreach(DirectoryEntry objChildDE in objDE.Children)
    Console.WriteLine(objChildDE.Path);
```

check [DirectoryEntry Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) constructors section, you can find some other ways too.

Anonymous access enabled to your AD, check [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/winserverManagement/thread/78376104-f892-47a8-99ba-626a3b4d7ba2).