# How can I access Active Directory data without exposing the password

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I am just learning to access my Active Directory and need to figure out if it is possible to access the information without having the user account password in the code. This code works:

```
DirectoryEntry SharePointUpdate = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + "comm2k8-dc3", "juser01", "password", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

When I try this code:

```
String strPath = "LDAP:// DC=MYOrganization"
DirectoryEntry SharePointUpdate = new DirectoryEntry(strPath);
```

I get this error

`"A referral was returned from the server.\r\n`

Am I missing something??

I do not want to have the user name and password in the code.  Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Is your AD configured to allow anonymous queries? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730486/accessing-ad-without-a-user-name-password-for-read-only-access for more information.

Comment: are you familiar with `PrincipalContext`

Comment: From your Tag `active-directory` I gleaned that you are in fact talking about an `Active Directory` and not an `Active Director` (missing **y** at the end). I edited your question accordingly and added some more useful tags pending approval/rejection.

Comment: NO Ad is not setup to allow anonymous queries.  I might have to explore encrypting the password??

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A referral was returned from the server" exception when accessing AD from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954170/a-referral-was-returned-from-the-server-exception-when-accessing-ad-from-c-sha)

Comment: The question was very similar, however the solution was to put the user name and password in the appconfig file.  Still did not resolve the problem of not wanting to expose that info.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code running in the context of either a domain service account or Network Service/Local System on a domain joined machine? If so, you can use that security context to access AD.

Your `LDAP://DC=MYOrganization` looks potentially strange. Is your domain really a single label domain called "MyOrganization", or does it have a legal FQDN? If it's called MyOrganization.net, for example, you would connect to `LDAP://DC=MyOrganization,DC=net`.